# Install SVN connector offline

Tags: eclipse, plugins, subversive

At work every developer has 2 computers :

- a computer connected to internet but through a proxy which prevent installing eclipse plugins with the marketplace or from an online repository.
- another computer connected only to the internal network where the development environment is installed, it will never access internet

Both computers use Windows 7.

I am not admin of either machine, USB ports are disabled on the 2nd computer, and I must ask the IT guys to transfer files from one machine to the other.

Currently we use eclipse Luna and we want to upgrade to Photon.
I can download eclipse and the subversive plugin on the first computer and ask to transfer files to the second.
On the other computer, I can unzip eclipse and install subversive offline from the zip package.
My problem is how to install svn connectors OFFLINE.

I did many searches on this site and with google, but I did not find any solution to my problem.
Everywhere I look, it tells to install the connectors from an update site, which is impossible for me.

I can download the connectors archive from http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/builds/ and transfer to the other computer but I don't know how to proceed from here.

To reiterate, I can only install eclipse plugins from zip files due to network limitation, so how do I install svn connectors OFFLINE.

Comment: There are different possibilities, e. g. copy the connector plug-in into the `dropins` folder, use p2 mirror task to mirror the connectors update site or create via p2 director an Eclipse distribution containing the connector. If an installation that contains the connector is available, you can install it via _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the archive for the connectors, do this.

Go to Help->Install New Software

Click the Add button that is to the right of the top text box then click the Archive 
button on the next page.

Browse to the archive that you downloaded and click Open.

At this point you can add an optional description and click Add.

You'll now see the features/plugins available and be able to select whichever you want. Then follow the install wizard as normal. I would have thought you'd done this already with the Subversive plugin but maybe you installed it another way.

Comment: I am an idiot. The first time I tried to download the connectors archive, it was from https://svnkit.com/download.php and these packages can not be installed in Eclipse. But the link I gave in my question offers installable packages. I was so sure to have tried both downloads, but it was not the case. Thank you.